# separate functions using matplot in R

Tags: r

I want to print a Brownian bridge (contains 5 paths) together with a line, and use black and blue color to separate them. However, when I use following code:

```
matplot(tseq,cbind(t(X),y),type="l", col=c("black","blue"))
```

[image]

It makes the first 3 paths black, and the rest 2 paths together with the line are blue. So I think it separates the color evenly as 3 and 3.

Then I used two plot functions and made it correct as

```
matplot(tseq,t(X),type="l", col=1)
lines(tseq,y,type="l",col="blue")
```

[image]

I just want to know if there is any way to correct my first code to make it to look like the second one? Thank you!

Comment: If you use `col = c("black", "blue"), then the recycling rule is used and the first column of `cbind(t(X),y)` gets the black colour, the second column gets the blue colour. Then the third column gets black and fourth blue, and so on. As the straight line is the last column, you could use following colours: `c(rep("black", 5),"blue")`

Comment: @MichalMajka It works, thank you!